# Looking for english/hindi commentary on parshuram kalpa sutra?

Tags: translation-request, resource, sri-vidya

Parshuram kalpa sutra is a manual for srividya. I am searching for good english and hindi commentary on it. Online or book links please.

Answer (score 7):

There is one Sanskrit-Hindi version available with Sanskrit and Hindi verses and commentary. Author is Dr. Paramhansh Mishra.

> [image]

One can buy the book from exoticindiaart; here is the link to that: [परशुरामकल्पसूत्रम् (संस्कृत एवं हिन्दी अनुवाद)- Parashuram Kalpa Sutra](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/parashuram-kalpa-sutra-NZF962/)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about English Translation yet but there are some Hindi translation available. One provided in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43474/277) is also good.

Sometimes, in addition to translation commentary would be more useful to understand the meaning in deeper way. [One book](http://chaukhamba.co.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=4668&search=kalpa+sutra) is available from Chaukhamba Surbharti Pratishthan publication:

> [image]

This is a Sanskrit text with Hindi Tika by Acharya Mrityunjay Tripathi. Will update the answer if I find any English translation.